# Drop down list with already defined Values MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a pre-defined drop down list for C# ASP.NET MVC2.  I am way confused on how to get this done...  Boy did we have it easy in vanilla asp.net...

But, let say I wanted the drop down list to have simple text like ... BMW, Audi, Mercedes, and values such as 1, 2, 3 or even "good", "better", "Best"... How would I create the Drop down list in the controller and how would I get it to the View?

What I have right now is

```
    List<SelectListItem> MRNList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem  { Text = "BMW", Value = "good", Selected = false},
        new SelectListItem  { Text = "Audi", Value = "better"},
        new SelectListItem  { Text = "Mercedes", Value = "Best"},                
    };
    ViewData["MRNDROPDOWNLIST"] = MRNList.AsEnumerable();.
```

In my view I have...

```
    <%:Html.DropDownListfor("MRN", ViewData["MRNDROPDOWNLIST"]) %>
```

What am I missing here?  I am getting a compile time error from Visual Studio telling me that I can't do that?  But the Parameter for DropDownList definitely says that you can use An IEnumerable list to fill that param?  I know I am missing something obvious here... Not sure what it is just yet... I will keep looking, but if any of you have any clues I would definitely appreciate it.

Derek

Comment: Just figure it out...  First thing... I was using DropDownListFor... I should have been using DropDownList()... Secondly, I need to cast my return from ViewData[] as a List of SelectedItems... That works and now I have a functioning drop down list... Thanks for the help anyway guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewData["MRNDROPDOWNLIST"]` is of type object and you will need to cast that to the correct type for the error to go away, which in this case would be to `List<SelectListItem>`:

```
<%:Html.DropDownListfor("MRN", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["MRNDROPDOWNLIST"])%>
```

Comment: That's actually a good solution.  I was going to answer my question but you did it for me.  Thanks.